# Tags could not be loaded in table details of Cloudera Hue

Tags: cloudera, impala, hue

I'm using Hue to access Cloudera Impala. When I open the table browser and view details of an arbitrary table, I get the error "Tags could not be loaded." How can I get the tags to load? Alternatively, is there a way to query the metadata and retrieve the tags?

Answer (score 0):

This would depend of the [Catalog connector](https://docs.gethue.com/user/browsing/#data-catalogs) used. In your case it is probably Cloudera Navigator and you should make sure it is up properly. Looking either at the Hue logs should explain if Hue could connect to it.